# How to echo custom startup message in vim

Tags: echo, startup, vim

Is there a way to echo a custom message in vim on startup? I tried using `echo "Message"` in my vimrc, but nothing seems to come up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably want to set up an `autocmd` to ensure everything is finished loading before your message appears.

```
autocmd VimEnter * echo "Message"
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres a command line version that might be helpful in tandem with some type of launcher:

```
vim -c 'e .|redraw|echom "Welcome!"'
```